# Using cron to launch python script in terminal window after reboot

Tags: python, cron, boot

I am trying to launch a python script automatically after boot.  I want to launch it in a terminal window because the program gives important feedback in the terminal.

I've researched many ways to do this including crontab, init.d, rc.local, and /etc/xdg/autostart/myscript.desktop.

When I've tested my script manually, calling rc.local from the terminal works, however none of these work after booting.

I've tried many variations, the latest in crontab:

```
@reboot sleep 60 && xterm -hold -e sudo python /home/pi/newcode/newcode/boot-test.py
```

Other variations I tried include (calling my python script from a shell script):

```
@reboot sleep 60 && /home/pi/bin/mount.sh && sh /home/pi/foo1.sh
```

and

```
@reboot sleep 60 && /home/pi/bin/mount.sh && sh /home/pi/foo1.sh
```

***Update:***

foo1.desktop (saved at /usr/local/bin/foo1):

```
[Desktop Entry]
...
Name=foo1
Exec=gksu /usr/local/bin/foo1
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=GTK;System;TerminalEmulator;
```

foo1 (saved at /etc/xdg/autostart/foo1.desktop):

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/x-terminal-emulator --command="/home/pi/newcode/newcode/boot-test.py" --title="My foo1"
```

python script, very simple for now (saved at /home/pi/newcode/newcode/boot-test.py)

```
sensortype=raw_input("press enter to continue")
```

Comment: Do you really need to print to the console?  Can't you just output to a log file and then tail the log file for the output if/when necessary?

Comment: maybe I don't, maybe I really want to do this because its giving me a hard time and I want to see it work.  I didn't think it would be this hard. I've also read many posts of others trying to do this, some with success...

Comment: Remove the`...`, these are only placeholder. Compare with a full blown example from your `/use/share/application` directory. Double-check your saved location, your given one are exchanged to my Answer. Add `python ` in front of the path to your `*.py`. Compare with my Answer. Edit your Question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

> **Comment**:
>   1. is named foo1.desktop ?
>   2. is named foo1.sh ?
>   3. does foo1.sh need to be made executable?

1. Yes, must be named ***.desktop**
2. If you use ***.sh**, the entry in *.desktop have to be equal
   `Exec=gksu /usr/local/bin/foo1.sh`
3. Yes, a Bash script have to made executable.

---

> **Question**:  I've test my script (rc.local) manually

Don't use `etc/rc.local`, it's executed to **early** for **X11**.

---

My `/etc/xdg/autostart` example:

1. Create a `foo1.desktop` with at least the following content:

> [Desktop Entry]
>   ...
>   Name=foo1
>   Exec=gksu /usr/local/bin/foo1
>   Terminal=false
>   Type=Application
>   Categories=GTK;System;TerminalEmulator;

2. Copy `foo1.desktop` or create link to `foo1.desktop` in `/etc/xdg/autostart`.
3. Create `/usr/local/bin/foo1` with the following content:

> #!/bin/bash
>   /usr/bin/x-terminal-emulator --command="python path_to_your_*.py" --title="My foo1"

4. Make `/usr/local/bin/foo1`, executable.

Comment: @stovfi: when I tried etc/rc.local I tried delaying the calling of my script with difeerent lengths of sleep, but that never worked. a few followup questions:
1.  is named foo1.desktop ?   
2. is named foo1.sh ?   
3. does foo1.sh need to be made executable?

Comment: still no good, my foo1.desktop scrpit: [link](https://pastebin.com/nCdBag5k), my foo1 script: [link](https://pastebin.com/FKWdHdvk) and my boot-test.py scrpit: [link](https://pastebin.com/fuQJfjQ9)

Answer (score 0):

After trying multiple variation the script that worked contained the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/x-terminal-emulator -hold -e sudo python /home/pi/newcode/newcode/hms2-v2.6.py
```

making the script executable by do the following was also necessary:

```
sudo chmod 755 /etc/xdg/autostart/foo1.desktop
```

I never got cron or init.d to work